# A peculiar limit?

Tags: limits

Consider $A^N = X$, where $A$ and $N$ are positive integers and $A > 1$. The ratio between $N$ and the number of digits of $X$ apparently have a limit(!). See these:

- $2^3=8$  (ratio $3 : 1$)
- $2^{13}=8192$  (ratio $3.25 : 1$)
- $2^{23}=8388608$  (ratio $3.2857 : 1$ )
- $2^{33}= \ldots$  and so on.

I used $2$ as a base because no other bases such as $3,4,5,\ldots$ give minimum number of digits for $X$, in other words, $2$ is the only base we need to calculate this limit, And if my calculation is correct, the first $5$ digits of this limit is $3.3219$, Is my calculation correct ?

Comment: Hint: The number of digits of $x$ is $\lfloor \log_{10} x \rfloor + 1$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas, yes I've already knew that : )

Comment: @ColmBhandal, I will be very very surprised if the limit 3.322.....

Comment: I'd like to add formatting to the post, do you have a problem with that?

Comment: @Zach466920, I'm sorry it was an accident

Comment: @gimimomani please ignore my earlier (now deleted) comment. I had misread your question. Hopefully now with these comments/answers you have the tools you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume we're working in our usual base ten number system. From Antonio's comment we have that the number of digits in the number $A^n$ is $\lfloor log_{10} A^n \rfloor + 1 = \lfloor nlog_{10} A \rfloor + 1$.

Now $\lfloor nlog_{10} A \rfloor + 1 = nlog_{10} A + \Delta$ for some $\Delta \in \{0, 1\}$. So the ratio is

$$ \frac{n}{nlog_{10} A + \Delta}$$

Clearly as $n$ goes off to infinity, the $\Delta$ becomes negligible and we're just left with:

$$ \frac{1}{log_{10} A} = log_{A} 10$$

as your limit. You can plug in $A = 2$ for your specific case and you should get the right answer.

Comment: you mean the limit is  1/ log2   ?

Comment: Yes, but note the log is **to the base 10**. You can also play around with bases using the standard log rules to end up with something like Zach's answer

Answer (score 0):

The limit is,

$$\log_{A}(10)={{\ln(10)} \over {\ln(A)}}$$

**Hint:**

Prove that the number of digits $D$ is bounded by,

$$\log_{10}(A^N) \le D \le \log_{10}(A^N) +1$$

You'll then want to find,

$$\lim_{N \to {\infty}} {N \over D}$$